# Android application get killed after screen locked for some time

Tags: java, android, android-activity, memory-leaks, bluetooth

I am developing an Android application involving recording data in bytes into file in phone storage from an external device that is connected via Bluetooth. I need the application to continuously run for few days without stopping.

I have tested for a few hours and the recording works fine while screen is ON. But when the screen is locked for more than a few minutes,in some devices like redmi phones, when i open the app again , it gets restarted again after stopping my app.This case happens when app is minimized for a few minutes.

I have searched on internet and came to know that applications are killed by android system when it is running on onPause for a some time inorder to save memory.

I am not sure if it is reason behind of that but if there is any other reason, please let me know.

Android working is as follows,

1. Establish Bluetooth connection between external device and android app.
2. I am using NRF BLE_app_uart library to get thing done.
3. Receiving data in bytes from external device to phone through bluetooth.
4. This data bytes are added to static arraylist and using an external runnable thread read values from arraylist and write/append into external file using Outputwriter method.
5. Data byte are simultaneously plotted in graph from external thread.
6. The tested device is Redmi Y2  (Android O , 8.1.0).

The problem is that when device is locked for more than few minutes , it gets destroyed and restarted again.

My doubt about reason is whether it is memory problem or android system doing.

Actually app is expected to run for few days and I wonder how various fitness apps are working for days.

Comment: THis is Doze mode.  Read up on it at https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Comment: @GabeSechan , Thanks for reply , I will read it and let u know

Comment: @GabeSechan , I read the document, but to solve Doze mode issue i can't ask users to accept REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permissions because it is not permitted Google play store, the other option available is using FCM but i am not sure whether it will work in my case. Please tell me any other ways to achieve it.Thank you

Comment: You can request that from the play store, but it doesn't turn off battery optimizations-  it lets you launch the screen where the user can choose to turn it off.

Comment: I can't really help you any more than that because I have no idea what you're doing other than using bluetooth somehow.  But the general rule is you can't expect your services to last very long unless they're foreground, and you can't expect anything to process more than once every 15 minutes when the screen is off.

Comment: @GabeSechan, Thanks for reply , can i  get clear , you are saying i can use REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permissions , so where should i give the permission ? and when. Is this permission solve my problem?

Comment: @GabeSechan, currently i am not using any foreground services , i am handling job in a seperate thread.Should i use foreground services?

Comment: You can, but that alone doesn't white list you-  it launches the settings page where the user would have to press a button to whitelist you.  As for foreground service-  how are you handling it now?  Putting it in your main activity?  Then yeah, once your activity goes into the background you'd be put high on the list of things that can be killed, and a foreground service is your best bet to stay resident a while-   but you'll still have Doze issues depending on when you're trying to read BT data.

Comment: @GabeSechan,  can foreground service run for long time while screen is off or whether it also get killed by android system,

Comment: Anything can be killed by Android if resources go low enough.  Foreground services are given higher priority to keep around when it kills things for resources.  Backgrounded activities are fairly low on the list.

Comment: @GabeSechan,thanks for reply , i will try to work it on a foreground service and test and let u know ,Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a foreground service.
The android documentation is here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Check this article for more infohttps://proandroiddev.com/background-ble-scan-in-doze-mode-on-android-devices-3c2ce1764570